# How to alternatively format excel, based on cell value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-2016

I have excel with data as below.

**Sample Data:**

[image: sample data]

I am trying to alternatively format my excel rows, when the value in classification, like below.
**Expected Output:**

[image]

**What I have tried:**

I am able to to do this for specific values, using `Conditional Formatting` >> `Highlight Cell Rules` >> `enter code here` >> `More Rules` >> `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` with below formulae:

`=EXACT($A2, "Design")`

[image]

**Where I am stuck:**

But, I have a lot more values in classification in my actual data set. Also we will keep on adding/removing the values from this column.

**Question:**

Is there a way to write a single which automatically format, whenever the data is refreshed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a helper column (E)

In E2, enter `1`

In E3, enter formula:

```
=IF(A3=A2,E2,-E2)
```

Copy this formula down.

Now use conditional formatting based on Column E.

Comment: Darn it, I was typing up the same answer - Beat me to it! Nice!!

Comment: works like a charm, thanks :)